# How can we implement CssClass active on link Button Click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, vb.net

On every linkButton Click, Event is handled
How can we change cssClass on link button click? Note that page refreshes on every button click.

Currently When I click on any LinkButton then by default it sets cssClass to Plus LinkButton

---index.aspx-----------

```
<ul class="mainMenu">
<li>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkHome" runat="server"><span>Home</span></asp:LinkButton>
</li>
<li>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkIndia" runat="server"><span>India</span></asp:LinkButton></li>
<li>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkWorld" runat="server"><span>World</span></asp:LinkButton></li>
<li>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkStates" runat="server"><span>States</span></asp:LinkButton></li>
<li>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCity" runat="server"><span>City</span></asp:LinkButton></li>
<li>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBusiness" runat="server"><span>Business</span></asp:LinkButton></li>
<li>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSport" runat="server"><span>Sport</span></asp:LinkButton></li>
<li>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkMagazine" runat="server"><span>Magazine</span></asp:LinkButton></li>
<li>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBlogs" runat="server"><span>Patrika Blogs</span></asp:LinkButton></li>
<li>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPlus" CssClass="active" runat="server"><span>Plus</span></asp:LinkButton></li>
```

---

### CSS Classes

```
ul.mainMenu{float:right; background:url(../images/menubg.gif) 0 0 repeat-x; width:100%}
ul.mainMenu li{float:left; color:#a7b5be; font-weight:bold; background:url(../images/seprator.gif) right 0 no-repeat; position:relative; z-index:999}
ul.mainMenu li a{color:#586066;line-height:24px;display:inline-block;}
ul.mainMenu li a span{color:#576067; padding:0 11px; line-height:24px; display:inline-block; }
ul.mainMenu li a:hover{background:url(../images/hover.gif) 0 0 repeat-x}
ul.mainMenu li a:hover span{color:#fff}
ul.mainMenu li a.active{background:url(../images/hover.gif) 0 -24px repeat-x;}
ul.mainMenu li a.active span{background:url(../images/redArrow.gif) center bottom no-repeat; padding-bottom:7px; color:#fff}
```

---

### VB CODE

```
 Protected Sub lnkHome_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lnkHome.Click
    If (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SeoFriendlyUrl") = "true") Then
        Response.RedirectToRoute("HomePage")
    Else
        Response.Redirect("index.aspx")
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub lnkAboutUs_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lnkAboutUs.Click
    If (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SeoFriendlyUrl") = "true") Then
        Response.RedirectToRoute("AboutUsRoute")
    Else
        Response.Redirect("AboutUs.aspx")
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub lnkContactUs_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lnkContactUs.Click
    If (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SeoFriendlyUrl") = "true") Then
        Response.RedirectToRoute("ContactUsRoute")
    Else
        Response.Redirect("ContactUs.aspx")
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub lnkFeedback_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lnkFeedback.Click
    If (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SeoFriendlyUrl") = "true") Then
        Response.RedirectToRoute("FeedbackRoute")
    Else
        Response.Redirect("Feedback.aspx")
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub lnkSiteMap_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lnkSiteMap.Click
    If (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SeoFriendlyUrl") = "true") Then
        Response.RedirectToRoute("SiteMapRoute")
    Else
        Response.Redirect("Sitemap.aspx")
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub lnkAdvWithUs_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles lnkAdvWithUs.Click
    If (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SeoFriendlyUrl") = "true") Then
        Response.RedirectToRoute("AdvertiseWithUsRoute")
    Else
        Response.Redirect("AdvertiseWithUs.aspx")
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub lnkPrivacyFooter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lnkPrivacyFooter.Click
    If (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SeoFriendlyUrl") = "true") Then
        Response.RedirectToRoute("PrivacyRoute")
    Else
        Response.Redirect("PrivacyPolicy.aspx")
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub lnkDisclaimerFooter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lnkDisclaimerFooter.Click
    If (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SeoFriendlyUrl") = "true") Then
        Response.RedirectToRoute("DisclaimerRoute")
    Else
        Response.Redirect("Disclaimer.aspx")
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub lnkNewsLetterFooter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lnkNewsLetterFooter.Click
    If (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SeoFriendlyUrl") = "true") Then
        Response.RedirectToRoute("NewsLetterRoute")
    Else
        Response.Redirect("NewsLetters.aspx")
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub lnkWorkWithUs_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lnkWorkWithUs.Click
    If (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SeoFriendlyUrl") = "true") Then
        Response.RedirectToRoute("WorkWithUsRoute")
    Else
        Response.Redirect("WorkWithUs.aspx")
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub lnkIndia_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lnkIndia.Click
    If (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SeoFriendlyUrl") = "true") Then
        Response.RedirectToRoute("CategoryRoute", New With {
                                                            .CatName = "India"
                                                            })
    Else
        Response.Redirect("Category.aspx?CatName=India")
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub lnkWorld_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lnkWorld.Click
    If (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SeoFriendlyUrl") = "true") Then
        Response.RedirectToRoute("CategoryRoute", New With {
                                                            .CatName = "World"
                                                            })
    Else
        Response.Redirect("Category.aspx?CatName=World")
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub lnkStates_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lnkStates.Click

End Sub

Protected Sub lnkBusiness_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lnkBusiness.Click
    If (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SeoFriendlyUrl") = "true") Then
        Response.RedirectToRoute("CategoryRoute", New With {
                                                            .CatName = "Business"
                                                            })
    Else
        Response.Redirect("Category.aspx?CatName=Business")
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub lnkSport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lnkSport.Click
    If (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SeoFriendlyUrl") = "true") Then
        Response.RedirectToRoute("CategoryRoute", New With {
                                                            .CatName = "Sports"
                                                            })
    Else
        Response.Redirect("Category.aspx?CatName=Sports")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use a combination of the ID of the link button and an ID assigned to the body tag of the page.

Lets take the India link for example. Your HTML markup would look something like this:

```
<body id="india-page">
<ul class="mainMenu">
<li>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkHome" runat="server"><span>Home</span></asp:LinkButton>
</li>
<li>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkIndia" runat="server"><span>India</span></asp:LinkButton></li>
<li>
</ul>
```

Then, your CSS stylesheet would look something like this.

```
#home-page ul.mainMenu li a#lnkHome {background:url(../images/hover.gif) 0 -24px repeat-x;}
#india-page ul.mainMenu li a#lnkIndia {background:url(../images/hover.gif) 0 -24px repeat-x;}
```

So every page that has a body id of 'india-page' will have the India link highlighted

Every page that has a body id of 'home-page' will have the home link highlighted etc

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using AspNet. Why not modify your LinkButton property for each trip from the server. Or have it as part of the state where in you can apply after the page reloaded.

Best

Answer (score -1):

On click of link button call jquery function as follows:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".lnkIndia").click(function () {

            $(".lnkIndia").addClass("Name of css class");
         }

     });
    </script>
```

add above script on you page, but this is for specific link button i.e. 'lnkIndia' for other you need to add same script with change in button

for common function you can use following code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function AddClass(IdOfLinkButton)
   { 
        document.getElementById(IdOfLinkButton).style.backcolor='red';
        document.getElementById(IdOfLinkButton).style.baorder='1px solid red';
   }
  </script>
```

and call this javascript function on click of link button as follows also don`t forgot to pass id of link button to the function on which you are calling functin.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkIndia" runat="server" OnClientClick="javscript:AddClass('lnkIndia');">
```